# Knockout JS validation message repeating twice

Tags: validation, knockout.js

New to Knockoutjs, Just trying to fix an existing bug in validation message. Below mentioned extend validation messages repeating twice in the UI.

```
$.each(viewModel.Form.Questions(), function () {
        var currentQuestion = this;
        debugger;
        $.each(currentQuestion.QuestionAnswers(), function () {
            var text = this.AnswerDisplay();
            this.AnswerValue.extend({
                required: {
                    message: text + " : Question price is required",
                    onlyIf: function () {
                        return viewModel.Form.FormPrice.PricingMode() == 2;
                    }
                },
                min: {
                    message: text + " : Question price should be a number",
                    onlyIf: function () {
                        return viewModel.SelectedQuestion() != null && currentQuestion.FormQuestionId() == viewModel.SelectedQuestion().FormQuestionId() && viewModel.Form.FormPrice.PricingMode() == 2;
                    },
                    params: 0
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: What does the bind look like in the html?

Comment: This could be caused because of a looping computed observables. For example where you compute observable 'B' based on observable 'A' and in observable 'B' you are changing observable 'A'. I have had similar issue where you would have to use `.extend({deferred : true});` on computed observables...

Comment: @dmoo there is no issue with the binding.    `self.viewModel.Errors(self.viewModel.errors());
        self.viewModel.errors.showAllMessages(); ` Array `self.viewModel.errors()` itself having repeated messages.

Comment: @Ramki Tried that no luck

Comment: Can you setup a working JSFiddle please?